# label's background color is disoriented on scrolling the Table view

Tags: ios

I am having a screen in which I am displaying certain information. There is a UILabel whose background color is set according to some conditions i.e either Blue,magenta etc. The problem is that as soon as I scroll down the Table the label background is disoriented and it's self adjusting itself. I am giving screenshot my Screen.

iOS Simulator Screen shot May 7, 2013 1.07.30 PM.png[image]

As you can see here how the label is disfiguring itself. The original label is the upper one and on scrolling it is giving me the disfigured one. I am also using [size to fit] command in the cellForRowAtIndexPath in the code. please suggest me a way to get through this. Is it due to the above command?

Comment: Try to call -sizeToFit in -tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Thanks buddy! but i have tried that also but it didn't worked. Moreover I have solved my problem with just 4 lines of code and now I am not facing the problem. Thanks again for the interest.